# In-house developer - don't know how much to ask for

Tags: raise, developer, new-hires

I graduated from High School in June of this year. I got hired to build a website in that same month, but rather than doing it as a freelancer I was hired into the company. There were a lot of holds on the project from the graphic designers, and the owner of the company thought to outsource the site to an external company and have me work on other things.

This last week I was told that I was going to make a website and that I should be asking for a raise. I currently make $10 an hour, but I have no idea how much I should be making. The company I work for is a multi-million dollar per year business, and I feel that $25/hour is a justified rate for someone with little experience and no degree, I hear that $40 is common for someone without much experience. Any help would be appreciated on what I should ask for and how I should ask.

I'm in Houston, Texas. Population center, but definitely not an oversaturated market.

Comment: So basically you were hired at a certain rate (which you accepted at the time), and now you are thinking that the rate is too small for the job?

Comment: @Brandin "I was told [...] that I should be asking for a raise" does not seem like it's his idea.

Comment: Anywhere between minimum wage and $400 an hour. Seriously tough, $10 is just as unlikely as these $400. The problem is, the company may or may not be interested in paying you fairly, and since they were willing to start you with $10, don't get your hopes up. Unless you were told by your boss to ask for a raise, go for the $25, which you might not get. If you were told by your boss to ask for a raise, be honest and ask the boss the same question you asked us (including the 25 and 40 numbers).
If you want a raise of 200% and more you'll usually need to change companies.

Comment: If someone within the organization has told you to ask for a raise, the reason for this, probably, is that the others are getting paid a lot more. Huge differences in pay can lead to ugly situations when word gets around (and it always does). Research salaries as Pete indicated, but also consider asking trusted colleagues (possibly your boss) what they think would be reasonable.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere The son of the CEO, I had a meeting with him and we spoke about how I'm being under compensated and I should be expecting a raise soon and to be prepared to ask for much more than I'm getting.

Answer (score 2):

Do what anyone else would do when setting their salary levels - look at jobs sites covering your general geographical and technology area.  Adjust for your skill levels or any niche value you might bring to the table (if you have a particular skill-set).

Doing this research will give you a representative pay grade to ask for. You might need to provide this research to validate your claim.

If your employer asks you why you chose a particular rate and you reply "I asked people on Stack Exchange", you might not get a favourable response.